# Plupload not uploading ({FileName}.part)

Tags: php, laravel, plupload

I'm using [Laravel Plupload Library](https://github.com/jenky/laravel-plupload) in my Laravel app.

It returns that in response when I'm trying to upload images:

```
jsonrpc:"2.0"
result : null
```

and It seems everything is ok.But still uploading like {FileName}.part in my upload dir.

I've checked my php.ini and nothing wrong.

(upload_max_filesize : 200M,max_upload_files: 200,post_max_size=200M)

My js codes :

```
 $("#image_uploader").pluploadQueue({
    runtimes : 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
    url : url,
    chunk_size : '1mb',
    rename : 'false',
    dragdrop: 'true',
    multiple_queues : true,
    filters : {
        max_file_size : '80mb',
        mime_types: [
            {title : "Image Files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png,jpeg"},
        ]
    },
    resize: {
        width : '300',
        height : '450',
        quality : '90',
        crop: 'true'
    },
    flash_swf_url : '/plupload/js/Moxie.swf',
    silverlight_xap_url : '/plupload/js/Moxie.xap',
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same issue with Plupload and the issue with the PHP rename function
rename("{$filePath}.part", $filePath);

It failed and the .part extension remained on the uploaded file. Not sure if your upload script has this step but thought it worth mentioning in case!